# Development VS A development

Tags: grammar, articles, zero-article, countability

This a brief description of a software project I was involved in:

> Project description:
>
> **Development** of market analysts's applications. [These applications allow you to ...]

Is it correct to use **Development** without any article in this context? What rule is it?

Comment: That's not a complete sentence. You aren't describing anything. It's possible it could work without an article, but I can't think of an example where it would. (Also, there does need to be an article, or something else, in front of *market*.)

Comment: Thank you! What I want to express is "The goal of the project is development of market analysts's applications" or "What we do is the development of  market analysts's applications" But I don't want to write the "The goal" because I put the heading "The project description:" before the actual description of the project. I've edited my question to make it more clear. Could you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Here, ***development*** is an **action noun**. That is a noun related to a process or activity; in this case, it is related to the verb *to develop*. It is used here as an *uncountable noun*, referring to the process of development in general. As a countable noun, development refers to things that have developed, such as:

> There has been **a new development** in the Watergate scandal.

Or to a specific instance of a process:

> The **development** of this new product has been fraught with difficulty

(note, however, that in that instance it works without the article, and it would mean the same thing)

As an uncountable noun, it can be used like you see in your example:

> **Development** of market analyst's applications depends on having accurate data and well-designed models.

(I have no idea if that's an accurate statement, I'm just stringing words together in a way that works semantically)

> We are proud to support **development** of open-source applications.

However, it should be noted in passing that the sentence featuring *development* in your example is not actually a true sentence. It is a sentence fragment, a bare noun phrase, and as such shouldn't usually be in the body of text. It could appear in dialogue, or as a heading.

Comment: Well, I thought this sentence look good after the heading "Project's purpose:" -  "Project's purpose: Development of market analysts's applications", doesn't it? How can I modify the sentence then so that it looks OK after "Project's purpose:"?

Comment: That really depends on how you've laid it out. (Also, I would say "Purpose of Project" rather than "Project's Purpose"; *project* should normally have an article, as it's a countable noun, but articles are often absent in headings.) As a sentence, you might say "The purpose of the project is (the) **development** of...", with the second 'the' being optional. "Development of market analyst's applications" should only appear like that if it's a heading, an item in a bullet list, or similar. If it's in the body text it will look wrong and/or sloppy.